# inserting timestamp into mariaDB table along with other variables

Tags: mysql, timestamp, mariadb

I am trying to add a current time stamp i.e. `now()` into my mariadb(SQL) table but running the script in terminal gives me an error.

The problematic part of this script is:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO outdoorsensorstable
     (time, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7)
     VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
     (now(), '', '', data4, '', data6, ''))
```

(Data 4 and data 6 are variables that have been generated in my script prior to this.)

The error I get is: `TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not callable`

I then try to resolve this by placing `now()` into the VALUES segment like this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO outdoorsensorstable (time, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7) VALUES (now(), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", ('', '', '', data4, '', data6, ''))
```

but I get another error on running the script:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Any ideas why and how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second effort is almost right; just don't pass any parameter for `NOW()`, because it is not a parameter as it is being hard coded:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO outdoorsensorstable (time, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7) "
sql += "VALUES (now(), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql, ('', '', data4, '', data6, ''))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How should I do that? I tried removing the quotation marks `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO outdoorsensorstable (time, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7) VALUES (now(), %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (, '', data4, '', data6, ''))` for the part that corresponds to now() but it gives another error

Comment: @Craver2000 I reformatted my answer so it is more readable.  Please have another look and comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Craver2000 The code you ran is _not_ what my answer says.  Either you copied wrongly or made a typo along the way.

Comment: I posted that comment just before I saw your re-edited answer. I did the changes as you advised, and it now works. Thanks alot for your help!